# Change event not updating selects with value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a change event that is working fine apart from the fact that it is not changing the val() values in my select elements. I have 2 selects that I wish to update on this change event so that the value becomes `val('')`. However, it is changing the `#dstrdept` select with data but it is totally ignoring the selects `#address, #box_dstr`.

I cannot see why it is not updating the values in these selects and would be grateful if someone could point out my error. Many thanks

I haven't posted the sql but assume all selects are populated with data.

**SOLVED**: Added `$("#address").trigger("chosen:updated");`

html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="rtvcompany" class="labelStyle">Company</label>
    <select class="form-control chosen-select" id="dstrcompany" name="dstrcompany" data-placeholder="Select a Company...">
      <option value=""></option>
      <?php
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultcmp)) {
            $name = $row["idcode_usr"];
            echo "<option value=\"$name\">$name</option>";

            }
      ?> 
    </select>
    <div id="compmessage"></div>
        <div class="servicesHelp">
        <lead id="serviceHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Please select a company to proceed.</lead></div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="rtvdept" class="labelStyle">Department</label>
        <select class="form-control chosen-select" id="dstrdept" name="dstrdept" data-placeholder="No departments to display...">
          <option value=""></option>

        </select>
        <div id="deptmessage"></div>
            <div class="servicesHelp">
            <lead id="serviceHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Please select a department where your box is stored for destruction.</lead></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="address" class="labelStyle">Destruction Address</label>
        <select class="form-control chosen-select" name="address" id="address" data-placeholder="No address to display...">
          <option value=""></option>
        </select>
        <div id="addrmessage"></div>
            <div class="servicesHelp"><lead id="addressHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Please select an address for the box destruction</lead>
            </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="box_rtv" class="labelStyle">Select Your Box(es)</label>
        <select class="form-control chosen-select" name="box_dstr[]" id="box_dstr" multiple data-placeholder="No boxes to display...">
          <option value=""></option>
        </select>
        <div id="dstrmessage"></div>
            <div class="servicesHelp"><lead id="serviceHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Please select your boxes from the list. You can select a max of 3 boxes per submission. You can select multiple boxes by holding the left ctrl on your keyboard and making your selection</lead>
            </div>
            <div class="noBrtvBoxes" style="color:white;"></div>
      </div>
```

js

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '#dstrcompany', function() {
    value = $(this).val();
    $(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="/domain/admin/images/loader.gif" alt="loading files" /></div>');
    $.get('/domain/admin/requests/boxes/destroy/loadboxDstrcompany.php?dstrcompany=' + value, function(data) {
      //console.log(value);
      $("#dstrdept").html(data);
      $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $("#dstrdept").val('');
        $("#compmessage").hide();
        $("#address").val('');
        $("#address").attr("data-placeholder", "Select your address");
        $("#box_dstr").val('');
        $("#box_dstr").attr("data-placeholder", "Select your box");
        //$("#rtvdept").attr("data-placeholder", "Select your new department");
       // $("#rtvdept").data("chosen").default_text = "New Default Text"
        $("#dstrdept").trigger("chosen:updated");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Where do you have 'addrmessage' div?

Comment: @G_S sorry should have been select element and not div. My bad. I shall update the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no placeholder with 'select' element, "data-placeholder" wont work in this case, need to add one 'option' and set its value attribute.

for address dropdown instead of this

```
 <select class="form-control chosen-select" name="address" id="address" data-placeholder="No address to display...">
      <option value=""></option>
    </select>
```

you can use

```
 <select class="form-control chosen-select" name="address" id="address" data-placeholder="No address to display...">
      <option value="0">Select your address</option>
      <option value="1">Addr1</option>
    </select>
```

and to set the value

```
$("#address").val(0);
//$("#address").attr("data-placeholder", "Select your address");
```

similarly for other select option

Comment: @k Problem with that is it makes the item selectable in the dropdown. Is there an alternative.

Comment: @k te other thing is why is it not updating the select with empty value as here: `$("#address").val('');` This has nothing to do with placeholder

Comment: Sorted it by doing `$("#address").trigger("chosen:updated");`. Thanks